# Как выглядят русские символы в памяти приложения?

Tags: память

Если открыть память приложения и полностью её просканировать, 
вырезав все лишнее, можно найти строки из собранного приложения.
Если строку "winduzsuxlol_123" найти проще простого, то как в памяти
приложения выглядят русские символы? Их совсем не хочет искать..
Я только начинаю разбираться, как работает память приложений и как в ней искать что-то.
Прошу Вашей помощи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зависит от реализации. Символы могут быть в кодировке win1251, могут быть в utf8/utf16 и т.д. И искать их нужно в соответствующей кодировке.

Comment: А где можно найти коды символов разных кодировок?

Comment: @AGrief вот для 1251: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251, а вообще должно искаться по запросу "X таблица".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!