# Проблема с поиском символов в памяти

Tags: c#, winapi, memory, кодировка

По "мотивам" [>этого вопроса<](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451099/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Использую данный код для создания массива с кодами нужных мне символов (брал из таблиц):

```
public ArrayList addRange(ArrayList link, int range1, int range2) {
    for (var i = range1; i < range2; i++) {
        link.Add(i);
    }

    return link;
}

public ArrayList GetAllowedChars() {
    var f = new ArrayList();

    f = addRange(f, 192, 255); //WINDOWS-1205
    f = addRange(f, 410, 450); //UTF-8 + WINDOWS-1205
    f = addRange(f, 41, 112); //UTF-8 + ASCII
    f = addRange(f, 30, 39); //UTF-8

    return f;
}

//Проверяю символ вот таким вот образом:

if (allowedr.Contains((int) c)) {
    // allowedr = GetAllowedChars();
    // c - char
    sb.Append(c);
}
```

Дамп стал выглядеть очень ужасно. Вот так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr7J3.png

Напомню еще раз, все байты идут из памяти процесса.

Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку? Моей задачей является найти русские символы.

Comment: `f = addRange(f, 410, 1103);` не выглядит правильным.

Comment: Что именно не так?

Comment: вы добавляете в этой строке 693 символа. это чё-то многовато, в русском языке столько нет

Comment: хм.. сейчас проверю..

Comment: Да, верно, ошибся, код поправил. Но все равно, теперь не ищет даже латинские символы.

Comment: Всё равно неправильно, по идее. Вы неверно обрабатываете двухбайтные комбинации символов. (Если к вечеру никто не напишет, как правильно, напишу из дому.)

Comment: Ищи ты UTF-16 что ли...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего не решать задачу вручную, а воспользоваться существующими библиотечными методами. Вы можете интерпретировать поток байтов как текст в какой-либо кодировке ([`Encoding.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) и отфильтровать символы нужного алфавита. Вот код для UTF-8:

```
var utf8enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(
        "UTF-8", new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderReplacementFallback("\0"));
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(PATH);
var text = utf8enc.GetString(bytes);
var russianChars = new HashSet<char>(
        "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ" +
        "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя");
var filtered = new string(text.Where(russianChars.Contains).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(filtered);
```

---

Если вы всё же хотите сделать это вручную, давайте подумаем, как.

Для начала, вы должны читать входной поток (файл, память, что угодно) по одному байту, а не по одному символу. Потому что символы в .NET двухбайтные.

Затем, для проверки на вхождение байта в промежуток разумно использовать два сравнения — с началом и концом промежутка. При этом сравнивать со значениями наподобие 410 смысла нет — у байта не может быть значение 410, максимум — 255.

Затем, найденный байт, даже если он и принадлежит нужному промежутку, нельзя просто так преобразовывать в символ и добавлять к выходной строке: ваша строка не обязана быть в соответствующей кодировке! Пишите код так, чтобы он не зависел от внутренней кодировки.

Затем, для поиска двухбайтовых символов сравнивать один байт вовсе не имеет смысла, потому что символ состоит из двух байт. Проверяйте байты по отдельности.

В итоге это выливается в следующие структуры данных:

```
interface ISymbolFilter
{
    bool FeedNext(byte b, ref char c);
}

class SingleRange
{
    public byte first;
    public string chars;

    public char? GetIndex(byte b)
    {
        if (b >= first && b < first + chars.Length)
            return chars[b - first];
        else
            return null;
    }
}

class SingleRangeWithPrefix : SingleRange
{
    public byte prefix;
    public bool foundPrefix = false;
}
```

Теперь нужно определить фильтры. Однобайтовый фильтр легче, поэтому покажу двухбайтовый:

```
class TwoByteSymbolFilter : ISymbolFilter
{
    IEnumerable<SingleRangeWithPrefix> ranges;
    public TwoByteSymbolFilter(params SingleRangeWithPrefix[] ranges)
    {
        this.ranges = ranges;
    }

    public bool FeedNext(byte b, ref char c)
    {
        bool result = false;
        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            var oldFoundPrefix = range.foundPrefix;
            range.foundPrefix = (b == range.prefix);
            if (!oldFoundPrefix)
                continue;
            var foundChar = range.GetIndex(b);
            if (foundChar == null)
                continue;
            c = foundChar.Value;
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Имея это, легко написать программу, которая будет фильтровать UTF-8:

```
class Program
{
    // это комментарий
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var utf8 = new TwoByteSymbolFilter(
                new SingleRangeWithPrefix() { prefix = 0xd0, first = 0x81, chars = "Ё" },
                new SingleRangeWithPrefix() { prefix = 0xd0, first = 0x90, chars =
                   "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмноп" },
                new SingleRangeWithPrefix() { prefix = 0xd1, first = 0x80, chars =
                    "рстуфхцчшщъыьэюя" },
                new SingleRangeWithPrefix() { prefix = 0xd1, first = 0x91, chars = "ё" }
            );

        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(PATH);
        foreach (var b in bytes)
        {
            char c = '\0';
            if (utf8.FeedNext(b, ref c))
                Console.Write(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Для других кодировок нужны, понятно, другие фильтры (более простые).

---

И да, .NET прекрасно приспособлен для подобных задач.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но к сожалению, дамп стал очень маленьким и ничего оттуда я так и не достал.

Теперь дамп памяти всего приложения выглядит так:
http://pastebin.com/Vh9Biesy

Хотя в приложении 100% есть русский текст. Что делать?

Comment: @AGrief: Ну это если вы ищете в utf-8. А текст может быть в другой кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

Скрин дампа не похож ни на один нормальный HEX-редактор, как минимум ошибка тут. Вы смотрите непонятно что непонятно в чем. Возьмите Hiew и нормальный дампер типа PETools, когда вы сможете в заведомо корректном дампе заведомо рабочим инструментом найти нужные данные - переходите к созданию своего "поисковика" и дампера. И да лучше С/C++, а не .NET

Comment: И как это отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: @VladD в вопросе написано "Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?"

Comment: А, вы формально. Ну, формально скрин дампа и не обязан быть похожим не hex-редактор. Претензии к UI — это мелочи, у ТС очевидная проблема с алгоритмом.

Comment: @VladD IMHO у ТСа нет ни одного заведомо корректно работающего инструмента под задачу, о чем и пишу.

Comment: А как вы видите, что инструментов нет, по скриншоту программы? о_О